# removing history from an git commit using egit plugin

Tags: git, history, egit

I committed something using wrong credentials, is there a way that I can remove that commit from git history. I am using egit plugin in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but not sure if you want to do it. Ponder the pros and cons, especially the big con of altering pushed history:

**Not pushed yet/local change only**

One the console just do one of these:

- `git rebase -i <commit before the one you want to remove>`: a file will open with the list of commits in a text editor. Remove the commit that you want to get rid of. Save and exit. Git will rebuild the history (and possible present some conflicts) without that commit.
- `git reset --soft <the commit you want to remove>`: use this option if you don't mind changing the rest of the history and commit it all over again. You won't have conflicts this way, but it's only *doable* if it's a short history.

**Changing remote branch**

Well, any of the solutions listed before, **BUT** when you push you have to specify `-f` option and this is EXTREMELY BAD :nucleardawn: ! You will be changing a commit history that others might be relying on, and it might completely screw their work.

Only do this if you're sure no one has fetched the remote branch for a while or if you work alone.

Hope this helps.